# Why was the HHL algorithm removed from the qiskit library?

Tags: qiskit, hhl-algorithm

I am a beginner in quantum computing and I was meddling with HHL algorithm for my class project. Turns out the linear solver algorithms (mainly HHL algorithm) are removed from qiskit library (see https://qiskit.org/documentation/release_notes.html) and now exist only as a [tutorial](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/ch-applications/solving-linear-systems-of-equations-using-hhl-and-its-qiskit-implementation).

I want to ask what is the reason of deprecation? Is it only useful for understanding quantum algorithms and has no applicability? I am asking this to understand why it is not supported before going on with the improvements done with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at section [4. Qiskit Implementation](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/ch-applications/solving-linear-systems-of-equations-using-hhl-and-its-qiskit-implementation#implementation) in the tutorial you will find a [repository](https://github.com/anedumla/quantum_linear_solvers) link where this repository now contains the HHL code that was formerly in Qiskit. You will see, if you read a bit further, the tutorial gives instruction for its installation as well.

Qiskit Terra 0.24 released yesterday (4th May 2023) and there is now an [Algorithms Migration Guide](https://qiskit.org/documentation/migration_guides/algorithms_migration.html) published that outlines the rationale for the removal of both HHL and Shor.

> Algorithms that were deprecated and are now removed entirely from
> qiskit.algorithms. These are algorithms that do not currently serve as
> building blocks for applications. Their main value is educational, and
> as such, will be kept as tutorials in the qiskit textbook. You can
> consult the tutorials in the following links:
>
> ```
>     Linear Solvers (HHL) ,
>     Factorizers (Shor)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Beyond what is mentioned in the main answer here, the Qiskit HHl implementation had a variety of [issues](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/pull/9832) that would need to be solved to go beyond the original [use](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.04484)